# Data frame modification - Rainfall intensities in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I have been working with the following data (which represents only a piece of the whole dataset):

```
a <- seq(ISOdatetime(2017,08,18,0,0,0), ISOdatetime(2017,08,18,0,8,0), "min")
b <- c(0.1, NA, NA, 0.1, NA, NA, NA, 0.1, 0.1)
df <- data.frame(a, b)
                    a   b
1 2017-08-18 00:00:00 0.1
2 2017-08-18 00:01:00  NA
3 2017-08-18 00:02:00  NA
4 2017-08-18 00:03:00 0.1
5 2017-08-18 00:04:00  NA
6 2017-08-18 00:05:00  NA
7 2017-08-18 00:06:00  NA
8 2017-08-18 00:07:00 0.1
9 2017-08-18 00:08:00 0.1
```

The column `b` represents measured values of the rain height [mm]. I need to get following results:

```
                    a   b     c
1 2017-08-18 00:00:00 0.1 0.100
2 2017-08-18 00:01:00  NA 0.033
3 2017-08-18 00:02:00  NA 0.033
4 2017-08-18 00:03:00 0.1 0.033
5 2017-08-18 00:04:00  NA 0.025
6 2017-08-18 00:05:00  NA 0.025
7 2017-08-18 00:06:00  NA 0.025
8 2017-08-18 00:07:00 0.1 0.025
9 2017-08-18 00:08:00 0.1 0.100
```

The columns `c` represents the modified column `b` as follows:

The values `df[2-4, 3]` are filled by the division of the number placed at `df[4, 2]` by the number represents number of all previous rows starting from the first row containing NA in the column `b` which appears at `df[2, 2]` to next NON-missing value `df[4, 2]` (including), i.e. 0.1/3 = 0.033.

Then, values `df[5-8, 3]` are filled by the division of the number at `df[8, 2]` (the next NON-missing value in the column) by number represents the sum of all previous rows starting from the `NA` in the column `b` which appears at `df[5, 2]` (= the first `NA` after the previous NON-missing value at `df[4, 2]`) to the next NON-missing value `df[8, 2]` (including), i.e. 0.1/4 = 0.025.

Finally, the value at `df[9, 3]` is equal the values at `df[9,2]` as there is any NON-missing value before the number at `df[9,2]`.

Is there anybody who is willing to help me with writing a code?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quite an extensive answer by iod, but I think it can be done a lot shorter.

We just need to know at which positions there are non-`NA`s, but it doesnt't matter what their actual value is. And then we can use `diff` to see how long the stretches are, and we can calculate the numerator and denominator for each row. My first code:

```
 counts <- diff(c(which(!is.na(b)), length(b)+1))
 num <- unlist(Map(rep, b[!is.na(b)], counts))
 denom <- unlist(Map(rep, counts, counts))
 result <- c(b[1], num/denom)[1:length(b)]
```

## Edit: correction

It turns out I hadn't read your question carefully enough, so my answer was slightly wrong. The original code looked *upward*, rows 2 through 4 were dependent on the value in column b, row 1.
But you need it to look downward, so my corrected code:

```
counts <- diff(c(0, which(!is.na(b))))
num <- unlist(Map(rep, b[!is.na(b)], counts))
denom <- unlist(Map(rep, counts, counts))
result <- c(num/denom)[1:length(b)]
```

Comment: Emil Bode, and what if the numerator is changing? What would you do than? Thank you in advance!

Comment: Then it also works like this. The second line in the code says: repèat each of the non-NA values in b, each `counts` times. So in this example 3 x 0.1, 4 x 0.1, 1 x 0.1, 1 x 0.1.
Which together makes a list of 9 numerators, and in this case those happen to be all the same. But if in the 4th row there was a 0.2, the numerator would be a vector `c(.1, .1, .1, .2, .2, .2, .2, .1, .1)

Comment: Emil Bode, I found out another problem (see below). Could you please take a look on it? Thank you so much!

Comment: Not as extensive as it seems - I got used to using that souped up rle function quite often, I don't really think about it that much. It loads automatically when I open R. The rest of my answer is quite simple.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution using the tidyverse plus a souped up version of `rle`:

First, let's create an `rle` that also counts NAs (from [here](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2011-June/281730.html)):

```
rlena<-function (x)
{
    if (!is.vector(x) && !is.list(x))
        stop("'x' must be an atomic vector")
    n <- length(x)
    if (n == 0L)
        return(structure(list(lengths = integer(), values = x),
            class = "rle"))

    #### BEGIN NEW SECTION PART 1 ####
    naRepFlag<-F
    if(any(is.na(x))){
        naRepFlag<-T
        IS_LOGIC<-ifelse(typeof(x)=="logical",TRUE,FALSE)

        if(typeof(x)=="logical"){
            x<-as.integer(x)
            naMaskVal<-2
        }else if(typeof(x)=="character"){
            naMaskVal<-paste(sample(c(letters,LETTERS,0:9),32,replace=T),collapse="")
        }else{
            naMaskVal<-max(0,abs(x[!is.infinite(x)]),na.rm=T)+1
        }

        x[which(is.na(x))]<-naMaskVal
    }
    #### END NEW SECTION PART 1 ####

    y <- x[-1L] != x[-n]
    i <- c(which(y), n)

    #### BEGIN NEW SECTION PART 2 ####
    if(naRepFlag)
        x[which(x==naMaskVal)]<-NA

    if(IS_LOGIC)
        x<-as.logical(x)
    #### END NEW SECTION PART 2 ####

    structure(list(lengths = diff(c(0L, i)), values = x[i]),
        class = "rle")
}
```

Now we can do this:

```
counts<-rlena(df$b)
```

Which gives us this handy table:

```
Run Length Encoding
  lengths: int [1:5] 1 2 1 3 2
  values : num [1:5] 0.1 NA 0.1 NA 0.1
```

Now to actually creating your column:

```
df$aux[cumsum(counts$lengths)]<-counts$lengths
```

This places the counts at the last position of each type of `b`. What we care about, though, is the strings of `NA`s:

```
                    a   b aux
1 2017-08-18 00:00:00 0.1   1
2 2017-08-18 00:01:00  NA  NA
3 2017-08-18 00:02:00  NA   2
4 2017-08-18 00:03:00 0.1   1
5 2017-08-18 00:04:00  NA  NA
6 2017-08-18 00:05:00  NA  NA
7 2017-08-18 00:06:00  NA   3
8 2017-08-18 00:07:00 0.1  NA
9 2017-08-18 00:08:00 0.1   2
```

Now all that's left is to create the `c` column:

```
require(dplyr)
require(tidyr)
df %>% 
  mutate(c=ifelse(!is.na(b) & is.na(lag(b)),b/(lag(aux)+1),b)) %>% 
  fill(c,.direction="up")
```

Result:

```
                    a   b aux          c
1 2017-08-18 00:00:00 0.1   1 0.03333333
2 2017-08-18 00:01:00  NA  NA 0.03333333
3 2017-08-18 00:02:00  NA   2 0.03333333
4 2017-08-18 00:03:00 0.1   1 0.03333333
5 2017-08-18 00:04:00  NA  NA 0.02500000
6 2017-08-18 00:05:00  NA  NA 0.02500000
7 2017-08-18 00:06:00  NA   3 0.02500000
8 2017-08-18 00:07:00 0.1  NA 0.02500000
9 2017-08-18 00:08:00 0.1   2 0.10000000
```

Comment: Thank you very much, iod. I will go trough and try to understand. I appreciate your time.